# Java prepared statement not working with auto increment

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

I'm trying to create a small test java restful web service to insert a record into the database.
My table is:

```
test (id int(5) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, name varchar(10))
```

When I try the following (with id changed every time), it works:

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into test (id,name) values (?,?)");
stmt.setInt(1, 1);
stmt.setString(2, "test");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

But when I'm trying to do this, its not working:

```
PreparedStatement stmt;
stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into test (name) values (?)");
stmt.setString(1, "test");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Here's the complete code:
**Database.java**

```
package dao;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class Database
{
    public Connection getConnection() throws Exception
    {
        try
        {
            String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rit";
            Connection connection = null;
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", "");
            return connection;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

**testService.java**

```
package webService;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import model.AccessManager;
@Path("/test/")
public class testService
{
    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    @Produces("application/text")
    public void setfood(@FormParam("name") String name)
    {
        AccessManager am = new AccessManager();
        try
        {
            am.setFood(name);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What means not working? Any exception you can Show us?

Comment: No, nothing gets returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its solved. I was doing a mistake. I had to set a default value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't should assing the value for id ( is automatically managed by db engine)

```
stmt = con.prepareStatement("insert into test (name) values (?)");
stmt.setInt(1, "test");
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried. See the 2nd part of my message. But its not working.

Comment: Have you looked in db ... ? .. no error ? .no result ? .. seems strange .. are you sure yu are calling the right function?

Answer (score 0):

Try use stmt.execute
When i use executeQuery i get Exception

```
Database database = new Database();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = database.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into test (name) values (?)");
            ps.setString(1, "test data");
            ps.executeQuery();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue data manipulation statements with executeQuery().
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:896)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkForDml(StatementImpl.java:463)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1926)
    at com.allex.test2.Start.<init>(Start.java:17)
    at com.allex.test2.Start.main(Start.java:9)
```

But then i use ps.execute(); All ok and in database apear new row :)

```
Database database = new Database();
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = database.getConnection().prepareStatement("insert into test (name) values (?)");
            ps.setString(1, "test data ");
            ps.execute();

            ResultSet rs = database.getConnection().createStatement().executeQuery("SELECT * FROM test");
            while(rs.next())
                System.out.println("ID:"+rs.getInt(1)+"  Name:"+rs.getString(2));

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
ID:1  Name:test data
ID:2  Name:test data
ID:3  Name:test data
```